# How to refresh the .m3u8 file, ie., the url used by the AVPlayer in case of Live broadcast?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have used an AVPlayer object to fetch the .m3u8 file from a remote server and play the video. My application has to stream live data, wherein the .m3u8 file would be updated (either new .ts files are added to the existing contents or the old ones are removed prior adding new .ts files) regularly. How do I make my AVPlayer respond to changing contents on server data. Precisely how to re-assign the url to AVPlayer. Below is the concise code. Please advise.

```
-(void) playVideo{
AVPlayerItem *contentPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:contentURL]]; // contentURL contains the path of live streaming data.
self.contentPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:contentPlayerItem]; //content player is an object of type AVPlayer
AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer =
  [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.contentPlayer];
//Then I add the AVPlayerLayer object onto my current view after setting its frame.
}
```

The question is when and how do I refresh the url, assuming the video is being played currently?

Comment: Doesn't the avplayer refresh the URL on its own?

Comment: I am not aware of it, because I din't find any thing about the auto refresh feature in AVPlayer Documentation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it refreshes on its own as long as it's not a VOD playlist.

Comment: That's just what I want then. Thank you.